# Cisco QoS for telephony and videoconference traffic

Tags: cisco, qos

I'm new in QoS and gathering information.
I have switches 2960, 3750 and routers 2911, 7200 and I have voip and videoconference device/software in my network that I want to pass to Internet through QoS rules.
Could you please suggest ways how could I setup QoS and what types of QoS I can use on the mentioned devices?

Thank you.

Comment: This is something that very few non-certified people do on their own. I highly suggest that you find a Cisco partner to help you out with this.

Comment: This is way too broad (and with way too many variables) to reasonably answer. Review the resources in [Jason's answer below](http://serverfault.com/a/525654/32986) and see if you can ask a more specific question, otherwise I would strongly suggest bringing in a consultant to work with you (particularly if the reliability and performance of these services are important to your company). You'll learn a lot by shadowing them on the design/implementation, and you'll get a well-designed, working environment when they're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a super long question!  The bible for this sort of stuff are the SRNDs (Solution Network Reference Design) produced by Cisco - in your case http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/solutions/Enterprise/WAN_and_MAN/QoS_SRND/QoS-SRND-Book.html

I hate to say "RTM" but in this case the topic is so complex and vast that we'd need more specific questions to fit an answer in to a forum like this.

I'm sure it's referenced in the Design Guide, but generally AutoQoS is your friend for deployments like this - it makes all of the configuration simple and best-practice based.   Here's the white paper explaining the technology http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk543/tk759/technologies_white_paper09186a00801348bc.shtml